# Invalid Operands to binary Expression, C

Tags: c

Im working on a function that takes some values and finds the min, max, and average of the values. I'm passing everything to the function by reference and am getting some errors when I try and do basic operations like `+` and `/` Namely the error is

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('double *' and 'double *')

```
void MinMaxAvg(double *pA, double *min, double *max, double *avg, int lines, double *total )
{
    for (int i=0; i<lines; i++)
    {
        if ( i==0)
        {
            min = &pA[0];
            max = &pA[0];
        }
        else
        {
            if (&pA[i] < min)
            {
                min = &pA[i];
            }

            if (&pA[i] > max)
            {
                max = &pA[i];
            }
        }

        total += &pA[i];     //<-- Errors on this line

    }

    avg = (total / lines);         // <-- Errors on this line.

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're getting some of the types confused there. In your example you're setting the *pointers* to a new value, not the value of said pointers.

The first would have to be:

```
*total += pA[i];
```

While the second should be:

```
*avg = (*total / lines);
```

In fact, you probably want to use floating point division on the second error there (some compilers are notorious for using integer divison in unexpected places):

```
*avg = (*total / (double)lines);
```

You'll still be getting errors if you do it like that, however. For example `&pA[i] > ...` will result in a pointer comparison, i.e. the *address* of the pointers will be compared. Most likely not what you want.

Comment: Thanks! That makes an infinite amount of sense! Completely solved my problems.

Comment: Which compiler would produce an integer division there?

Comment: glad it helped ya ;) -- @larsmans I've seen at least some versions of Borland's compiler suite produce integer divisions in cases like that. But strangely it didn't always do so. Seems to be a bug in some versions, but I'm guessing it won't be the only compiler to do that. There's no harm in adding the cast though, so better safe than sorry, right?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to add an address to a pointer, that's not a valid operation.

You probably meant:

```
*total += pA[i];
```

Your use of `&pA` seems very confused, as does the re-assignment of the pointers `min` and `max`.

If you have a pointer to a value (like `double *min`), then `*min` is how you access (read or write) the value being pointed at.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "pass by reference" in C language unlike C++. You should dereference each pointer in your code if you want work with variables values. Now you work with variables addresses.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by this as my code seems to be working just fine.